# Jquery dynamic div

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, jquery-ui

Im using the following jquery to dynamically add a form element in my rails view..The add button works but the remove button is not clickable..

```
$(document).ready(function() {
           $('#btnAdd').click(function() {
               var num     = $('.clonedInput').length;
               var newNum  = new Number(num + 1);

               var newElem = $('#input' + num).clone().attr('id', 'input' + newNum);

               newElem.children(':first').attr('id', 'name' + newNum).attr('name', 'name' + newNum);
               $('#input' + num).after(newElem);
               $('#btnDel').attr('disabled','');

               if (newNum == 5)
                   $('#btnAdd').attr('disabled','disabled');
           });

           $('#btnDel').click(function() {
               var num = $('.clonedInput').length;

               $('#input' + num).remove();
               $('#btnAdd').attr('disabled','');

               if (num-1 == 1)
                   $('#btnDel').attr('disabled','disabled');
           });

           $('#btnDel').attr('disabled','disabled');
       });
```

Here's the form code:

```
<form id="myForm">
    <div id="input1" style="margin-bottom:4px;" class="clonedInput">
        Name: <input type="text" name="name1" id="name1" />
    </div>

    <div>
        <input type="button" id="btnAdd" value="add another name" />
        <input type="button" id="btnDel" value="remove name" />
    </div>
</form>
```

THANKS!!!!!

Answer (score 1):

try this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/269HU/

```
use $("#id").attr('disabled',false);   --> for enable
```

and

```
use $("#id").attr('disabled',true);   --> for disable
```

Answer (score 0):

Try removing

```
.click(function() {
```

with this

```
.on('click',function() {
```

Comment: use class instead of id . and use $(this) inside function to indicate clicked element.

Answer (score 0):

`$('#btnDel').attr('disabled', '');` doesn't actually remove the `disabled` property - it just sets it to the empty string, and it's still active when blank!  Use this instead:

```
           $('#btnDel').removeAttr('disabled');
```

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/LzdHg/

Answer (score 0):

Answer is found and explained here... http://digitalmeaning.co/thoughts/using-jquery-to-duplicate-a-section-of-a-form-maintaining-accessibility/

“For later version of jQuery, change the button code to either

$(‘#btnDelW1′).attr(‘disabled’,true);

or

$(‘#btnDelW1′).attr(‘disabled’,false);

Answer (score -1):

Try live method of jQuery

```
$('#btnDel').live('click', function() {
               var num = $('.clonedInput').length;

               $('#input' + num).remove();
               $('#btnAdd').attr('disabled','');

               if (num-1 == 1)
                   $('#btnDel').attr('disabled','disabled');
           });
```

http://api.jquery.com/live/

Comment: -1 because .live in deprecated in new jquery instead use .delegate or .on method.

Comment: see the attached link of yours. it is in depreciated  category.